# Proving $ 1+2f'(x)+\frac{2}{x(1+x^2)}\left(\frac{3x}{2}+f(x) \right)\ge \frac{6x^2}{1+8x^2} $.

Tags: analysis, derivatives, inequality, cubics

> Put
> \begin{align*}
> f(x)=\left( -\frac{x}{2} +\sqrt{\frac{1}{27}+\frac{x^2}{4}}  \right)^{1/3}-\left( \frac{x}{2} +\sqrt{\frac{1}{27}+\frac{x^2}{4}}  \right)^{1/3}
> \end{align*}
> Prove that
> $$
> g(x):=1+2f'(x)+\frac{2}{x(1+x^2)}\left(\frac{3x}{2}+f(x) \right)\ge \frac{6x^2}{1+8x^2}
> $$

**My attempt**

I put
\begin{align*}
A=\left( -\frac{x}{2} +\sqrt{\frac{1}{27}+\frac{x^2}{4}}  \right)^{1/3}\quad
B=\left( \frac{x}{2} +\sqrt{\frac{1}{27}+\frac{x^2}{4}}  \right)^{1/3}
\end{align*}
and then
\begin{align*}
f'(x)=-\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{A^2-AB+B^2}
\end{align*}
where $AB=\frac13$. But I don't know how to continue. I know that $g(x)$ is an even function. Via mathematica I find that
$$\left[(1+x^2)g(x)\right]'\ge 0\quad \forall \,x>0$$
But I also can't prove this. Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the substitution $B = ( \frac{x}{2} +\sqrt{\frac{1}{27}+\frac{x^2}{4}} )^{1/3}$
(correspondingly, $x = B^3 - \frac{1}{27B^3}$ for $B > 0$), we have $f(x) = \frac{1}{3B} - B$ and
$f'(x) = -\frac{3B^2}{1 - 3B^2 + 9B^4}$. Then it suffices to prove that $F(B) \ge 0$ for all $B > 0$
where $F$ is some polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint.

Let $f(x)=y$.

Thus, $$y^3+y+x=0,$$ which gives $$3y^2y'+y'+1=0$$ or $$y'=-\frac{1}{1+3y^2}$$ and we need to prove a polynomial  inequality of one variable $y$.

I got that finally we need to prove that:
$$y^2(6y^{14}+16y^{12}-10y^{10}+y^8+94y^6+94y^4+26y^2+1)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: i think you used the cardano's formula in the first line

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore Yes, of course. It's possible because $\frac{1}{27}+\frac{x^2}{4}>0.$